# Use only a single controller in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to develop an app where I only want one controller, and use anything in the url as an argument to that controller.

I've read that normally the url is parsed as GET controller/action, as in example.com/controller/action/params, but I would like to use a specific controller and a specific action.

Is there any way essentially to parse a url as example.com/params, always handled by the same action and controller?

Comment: What's your reasoning for doing this in the first place?

Comment: Based on the description you've given I would recommend to use other framework such as Sinatra or Padrino.

Comment: I'm essentially trying to imitate functionality seen in url shorteners or imgur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of examples of this in the Rails guide on [routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints). The file `config/routes.rb` is where you set up the mapping from URL's to controllers.

One specific example is this:

```
match '/:username' => 'users#show'
```

Any request that doesn't match further up will get routed to the `UsersController`'s `show` method, with the string passed in the `params` hash as the value of the `username` key.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. In your `config/routes.rb` file define the route:

```
match "catchall/*page", :to => "catchall#respond"
```

Then in your controller:

```
class CatchallController < ApplicationController

  def respond

  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is bad idea, but you can do this, using render action:

```rb
def index
  if self.class.instance_methods(false).include? params[:page].to_sym
    render action: params[:page]
  else
    #error_404
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this a bad idea just when using with rails? I'm essentially trying to mimic imgur functionality, where an image can be retrieved simply via imgur.com/AbcDefg

Comment: Now I understand your idea  and my answer looking so incongruous(